# Simple Code and Challenge on Operation (with picture)

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, code-analysis

I ran into the following pseudo code. Here `A` is an array of integers:

```
for i = 1 to n 
{   
    j = i; f = 1;

    while ((j>1) and (f==1))
    {
        if (A[j]<A[j/2]) { swap(A[i], A[j/2]); j = j/2; } 
        else             { f = 0;                       }
    }  
}
```

I couldn't understand why always the minimal element of `A` goes into `A[1]`.

In fact I have a problem with, how this code change the `A[1]`? Or at least if I correctly understand the operation of this code?

Comment: Dear @KerrekSB, i do it know...

Comment: Look at how other questions on this site are presented: *type* the code, and format it as code. Don't paste a screenshot of text. The screenshot isn't editable or copy/pastable.

Comment: Dear @KerrekSB, i do it. would you please waste your valuable time to minor edit it ?

Comment: Done. Please look at the changes I made (consistent spacing, formatting inline code with backticks, and disabling syntax highlighting). Whether my time was wasted will be up to you -- it's never a waste to teach something useful!

Comment: Dear @KerrekSB, thanks so much. i learn it. lot's of thanks.

Comment: The active part of the algorithm is the `swap`. The logic hinges on how integer division works (e.g. `1 / 2` is `0`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is not clear how the integer division should work (`3/2 == 1` or `3/2 == 2` ?)  the algorithm will always move the min value to the first position of the array.

E.g. for an array composed as `{4,5,6,2}`, the last element will be first moved to the second position with the first swap (`j==4` and `i==4`) leading to this situation: `{4,2,6,5}`.
When `j` will be updated to `j/2 --> 2` the second element of the array `2` will be compared with the the one of index `j/2 --> 1` and moved to the first position. Here the problem with the division rises up.

The division `1/2` represents a risk since it is can be converted to `0` leading to a call for `A[0]` and resulting in an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`, but this is psuedocode and it could work if you round up the result of the division.

Comment: It could also be that arrays are zero-indexed and you would *want* `1/2` to be `0`.

Comment: I grew up with the indexes starting from `1` in pseudocode, ofc this is not a standard. In that case the algo would not move the min element to `A[1]` but to `A[0]` if I'm not wrong...

Comment: If I may give you an advice: when you have situations like these, run the algorithm on paper with a real example, it always helps to understand it ;)